# Do generics in Delphi cause performance bottlenecks?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe3

Recently i have been developing an application and wanted to have a collections of several types. I don't want to declare and implement a new collection class for it's type. So, i thought of going with generics, but wasn't sure about the performance of Generics compared to normal typed instances. Performance is the major thing that i am looking at. My application is time critical and even loosing few 100 milliseconds is also not advisable.

I am using Delphi XE3

For eg:

```
ICollectionItem = interface
  function GetID : string;
  property ID : string read GetId;
end;

TGenericCollection<T: ICollectionItem> = class
  function Add(T) : Integer;
end;
```

compared to

```
TSomeClass = class(TInterfacedObject, ICollectionItem)
  function GetId : string;
end;

TSomeClassList = class
  function Add(item : TSomeClass) : Integer;
end;
```

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I don't have XE3 either, so I didn't answer, but in earlier versions, generics aren't optimised very well at all. They seem to get compiled to some sort of pseudo-assembly that gets patched up when the generic gets instantiated, and as a result, optimisations that could otherwise be used (even as simple as evaluating `SizeOf(T) + 1` at compile time) aren't.

Comment: See [`"Using Generic containers in Delphi XE - always?"`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5313756/576719). Better performance since optimization can do a better job. See also [`"Overview of Generics"`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Overview_of_Generics). At instantiation there might be a performance penalty.

Comment: Did you verify that your collection code is your application's bottleneck? Also, TSomeClassList.Add is wrong in the Q. Parameter needs to be ICollectionItem. Is that just a typo? If you want to compare performance, what's stopping you. Trying to pre-judge it only gets you so far. Write two versions of the code and time them both.

Comment: I don't think there is any noticeable difference in speed but there is in size. Currently compiler generates code for each concrete type, even if some types could share the implementation.

Comment: Agree with hvd.  In theory generics should be the same or better - in practice the compiler isn't good enough + often produces much slower code when using generics. eg. it won't inline functions that use generics (in XE2 anyway).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No performance bottleneck

Delphi generics are *compiled*. The compiler knows the concrete types at *compile* time and it's going to do it's best to provide you with the best code it can. There should be no differences between generic and non-generic code when inspecting the generated code at run time.

There's a good chance to get better code with generics, because you're more likely to use ready-made, efficient, type-safe data structures. When rolling your own you're likely to cut corners because lets be honest, writing sorting algorithms, efficient allocation, etc is *hard*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, just read Barry's blog all the way back to 2007. No mention of how the two-stage compilation works. It makes some sense as the units declaring generic types need to be compiled to `DCU` and that can't possibly contain final code, but I found nothing on it. If you have a link, please share.

Comment: I found this article which touches on the subject: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/10/01/38465/ If you think about it, it has to be a two stage process. For example, when you compile against the DCU file containing `TList<T>`, that no longer has the source code for `TList<T>`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for the link. "Touches" indeed - I wish I had more information.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the informative link..I would test the performance with the generics and typed lists..