# Are there any penalties for using generic types in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I was reading about C++'s templates, which incur in higher compile times, and thought about Delphi's [generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Overview_of_Generics), with which I haven't experienced any noticeable  changes in compile time. I was wondering if there are any performance penalties or otherwise, for instance increased code size. I've found [this blogpost](https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2014/03/why-delphi-generics-are-annoying.html) from 2014 (with an update from 2015) mentioning increased code size with generics but some improvements in later versions. There's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14827713/7050476) from 2013 mentioning no performance loss by using generics (but nothing about code size). Is it (still) correct to assume no performance loss but a possible increase in generated code size? I would love to know how the generic types are actually implemented, but just knowing if there are any penalties is already good.

Comment: Yes, [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14827713/8041231) still applies. If you declare a specific generic type, the compiler will create a specific type for you (which increases the size of the binary).

Comment: @Victoria: that is true, but there have been a few changes. Take a look at the source of, say `TList<T>` and you'll see a lot of code for different purposes. Through the use of new intrinsics, the compiler manages to only compile the relevant parts, optimized for the type. This way, common code doesn't have to be compiled twice. That only works if the class is built upon it, though. It makes listings less readable, but more optimized WRT speed and space.

Comment: There is indeed no performance loss. The code that is generated is for the specific type only, so no runtime checks are necessary, code for floats is different from code for integers, etc. But there is conditional compilation now, using the new intrinsics, so there is less code bloat if your code uses them judiciously.

Comment: Note that many methods of TList<T>, TObjectList<T> is slower then of TList, TObjectList. Especially Add, Sort, IndexOf and replacing item by index. (tested with XE2)

Comment: See this open bug report: [RSP-16520](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16520). This is still a painfull issue!

Comment: @RM: that could be different in 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: @RM That makes not much sense because TList holds pointers and the generic collection can hold anything. Who knows what you tested but without anything to backup your claims it smells like FUD.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I won't share my test app here but if you look at the implementation it is pretty obvious that the generic Indexof method will be slower.
TList.IndexOf uses simple equal test (P^ = Item) while the generic list calls FComparer.Compare which in case of a pointer will be a function call + 2 is higher/is lower compare plus an is equal compare operations on the result. Done for each item until a match has been found

Comment: @RM. What about a type that is larger than a pointer. Then your `TList` code has to store pointers to items. Typically this means that they won't be contiguous and in that case memory access patterns are worse which affects performance. Isolated micro benchmarks (especially ones that we cannot see) aren't very useful.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. So what about a type which is a pointer? Would you think TList or TList<T>will be faster or slower?
Or TObjectList and TObjectList<T>?

Comment: @RM. In that case TList for the reasons that you outline. However, as I said, such micro benchmarks are often misleading and real world performance is not likely to be impacted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you have an example benchmark for non pointer type?

Comment: @RM. No, but I'm not the one making specific claims am I?

Comment: "Typically this means that they won't be contiguous and in that case memory access patterns are worse which affects performance. "