# Delphi DCU files in git?

Tags: git, delphi, gitignore

Note: I have no experience in Delphi programming.

*My problem:*

-I would like to put an old Delphi project of a collegue into a git repo.

-I read that [DCU files are compiler generated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24666172/7559642) and even found a .gitignore template actually ignoring these files.

-After putting everything together and cloning the repo, the Delphi 
compiler complains about missing DCU files in the fresh clone.

-When I add the DCU files to git, everything compiles fine.

-The DCU files (at least most of them) get modified during the build process.

-Obviously, the DCU files mess up the git history and make diff's hard to read, but a project that doesn't compile is unacceptable.

What is going wrong here? Are there errors in the code when the DCU files are required for compiling? Is it correct that the compiler is asking for the files during build process? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The compiler (**not** interpreter) surely tells you what DCUs are missing. Look if there are corresponding *.pas files, i.e MyTools.pas if the compiler complains about missing MyTools.dcu.

Comment: Your problem is not the fact `DCU` files are missing, but the fact compiler cannot find your appropriate `PAS` files in order to compile them. You have to fix project search paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was indeed that 3rd party libraries were inside the actual source like mentioned by Turrican and Rudy Velthuis. Compiling the project showed us which dcu files came from 3rd party and afterwards we had to decide for each dependency what to do with it (we got rid of some, some had to stay, because there was no way to get the source sadly). The comments by Rudy Velthuis helped a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi programs are made by linking the DCU's you need together.
The pas-files will be compiled to dcu files.

If for a program you don't have all the pas-files but you do have the DCU files then it can still compile.

So I would try the following: try compiling your project by removing all the modified DCU files.

This way you can find out which DCU-files you have source code for and which you don't.

Comment: As pieter says, DCU are compiled units. Is not recomended put binaries on a source repo for obvious reasons. You need every .pas unit used by your project. If there are 3r party units you are using in the project don't put on your git repo directly,

Comment: Thanks! This is great information for me. Indeed the project contains some 3rd party libraries. I will check the DCU files together with the programmer and report results. I assume this suggestion by Pieter B (and the others) is the correct answer.

Comment: If the Delphi system can't find certain 3rd party files, be sure to adjust the Search path in the compiler options so it can find them. If you don't have them yet, install them. Perhaps you can use Tools/GetIt package manger to install them, or get them from that 3rd party directly.

Comment: Also note that .dcu are version-dependent. You can't use .dcus generated by one version of the compiler with code generated by another version of the compiler. That is why most Delphi programmers prefer to have the source code (.pas, inc, dpr, .dpk) files for everything, so they can recompile if that is necessary.